# GapDebug: How to use GapDebug wireless?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, gapdebug

Is it possible to use GapDebug without data cable?
I want to debug my apps using GapDebug without data cable so I was hoping to find some solution for it.

I'll appreciate any contribution.
Thanks